# Jquery :first selector give second element instead of first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want select first row from any cell so I just wrote javascript like.

```
  var curcontrol = $("#cellno_111");
    var firsttd= $(curcontrol).parents("table tbody tr:first");
    alert($(firsttd).text());
```

**And my table is below**

```
<table id="idTable_1" border="1px" width="97%" class="tblDragTable" data-numberofrows="2" data-numberofcolumns="2">
    <tbody>
    <tr id="trno_10">
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_100">0</td>
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_101">0</td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="trno_11" height="1">
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_110" width="1">1</td>
        <td class="tblCell selectedCell" id="cellno_111" width="1">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when I use `find()`  it giving me correct result

```
 var curcontrol = $("#cellno_111");
  var firsttd= $(curcontrol).parents("table tbody").find("tr:first");
```

But I just want to know why the above code return second `tr` instead of first `tr`

HERE IS MY JSBIN [http://jsbin.com/lisozuvade/1/watch?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/lisozuvade/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it fails is because calling `parents` with a filter of `table tbody tr` will only match the immediate parent `TR`. The other TR falls outside of the ancestors so `:first` will match *the only* `TR` it finds.

If you try this you will see what is going on:

```
alert($(curcontrol).parents('table tbody tr')[0].outerHTML);
```

returns this:

```
    <tr id="trno_11" height="1">
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_110" width="1">1</td>
        <td class="tblCell selectedCell" id="cellno_111" width="1">1</td>
    </tr>
```

then try this:

```
alert($(curcontrol).parents('table tbody')[0].outerHTML);
```

which returns this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="trno_10">
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_100">0</td>
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_101">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trno_11" height="1">
        <td class="tblCell" id="cellno_110" width="1">1</td>
        <td class="tblCell selectedCell" id="cellno_111" width="1">1</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j28g27m1/

So your first example only looks at the ancestors (one `TR`) and returns the first match. The second example looks further back up the tree, then finds *all* `TR`s in the `tbody` then chooses the `first` one.

A preferred, slightly faster, way would be to use `closest()` and `find()`

e.g.

```
var curcontrol = $("#cellno_111");
var firsttd= $(curcontrol).closest("tbody").find("tr:first");
```

or faster yet (as selectors are evaluated right-to-left):

```
var curcontrol = $("#cellno_111");
var firsttd= $(curcontrol).closest("tbody").find("tr").first();
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j28g27m1/1/

Comment: Great *** calling parents with a filter of table tbody tr will only match the immediate parent TR*** but  still confused  .. why `table tbody tr` match first element when  I used `parents()`   is that  `J-query` behavior ??

Comment: @Anant Dabhi: In `parents`, any selector is purely a filter, applied to the collection of parent, grandparent, great-grandparent etc. The only element that matched the entire selector was the *immediate* parent `TR`, not the first `TR` in the table. If you need more explanation, just ask.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for parents of `#cellno_111`, only that `tr` is.

Also keep in mind that `:first` is like `.first()` as it filters to the first element in the set of matched elements, it has nothing to do with being the first child of something. If you want multiple elements, which are first children you should use `:first-child`.

`.parents(table tbody tr:first)`: query the parents  of the element for a `tr` which is inside of `table` and `tbody`, then pick the first

`.parents("table tbody").find("tr:first")`: query the parents of the elements for a `tbody` which is inside a `table`, then find all `tr`s inside of it, then pick the first of them

PS: I suggest using `closest` instead of `parents` as the go-to DOM navigation method for ancestors; most of the times it's way more practical and easier to understand.

Comment: This answer in incomplete (and slightly ambiguous). Please provide an example of how they should do it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie the question is `But I just want to know why the above code return second tr instead of first tr` this answers that

Comment: Sorry, but I see now it is simply I could not understand your grammar. I added my own explanation with some practical examples.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to understand what each selector is doing. Try with several console.log, you'll see:

```
$(curcontrol).parents();
```

This return a set of elements. In this set, there is only 1 `tr`, the parent of your `curcontrol` td tag.

You can indeed filter this specific set by adding a extra filter :

```
$(curcontrol).parents("table tbody tr:first");
```

But as I just explained, the original set only contains a single TR, so the first one returned is actually the only one returned.

Your `find()` approach is different, you specify a specific (parent) element and with the `find()` you search trough children, which explains in this case the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the parent hierarchy of `cellno_111` is:
`trno_11` -> `tbody` -> `table`

In your first example, the first `tr` parent `cellno_111` finds is `trno_11` and not `trno_10`. It does not have a `trno_10` parent.

The reason it does work with `find()`, is because you select the `tbody` and then search for the first `tr` child the `tbody` has.